# PHP not executed on apache Alias with Virtualmin

Tags: php, apache, alias

I've got two virtual servers in webmin:

- domain.com
- crm.domain.com

Because I’m using AngularJs on domain.com to get data from crm.domain.com I have trouble because of cross-domain requests.

What I want to do is an Alias `domain.com/crm` to point to the same website at `crm.domain.com`.

I have put the alias in virtualmin but when I open `domain.com/crm` the PHP script is not running, instead, it outputs directly the php code.

So is there a way I can get php running on the alias?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to somehow solve my problem by doing the following:

I've renamed the Apache Directives for the virtual server from /home/servername/public_html to /home/servername. That way Directives that were for public_html apply to superior folder too.

Then I've created a symlink named /home/servername/crm that points to /home/servername/domains/crm.domain.com

And last I've added on the main domain the Alias /crm to point to the symlink /home/servername/crm

For now it worked.